# Placing element in an array masm

Tags: arrays, pointers, indexing, masm

I want to replace the last element of an array.

For argument sakes I want to replace element z with q.

```
siz db 3

array db x,y,z

q db 0

    mov si, offset array;;;si pointing at array address
    mov al, [si];;;al = arrayAddress value
    add al, siz;;;al = arrayAddress + arrayLength
    mov si, al;;;si pointing at the last element of the array

    ****mov [si], q;;;move variable into last element of the array
    dec si;;;decrement pointer(point at k-1);;;for later loop

    mov dl, [si];;;get last element of array and print char 
    add dl, 30h
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
```

So from what I understand I want to use the pointer to point at the array then index using the size to the last element.

The part where I get confused is on how to move a variable value into the element into the position I am pointing at.

I am getting an error (improper operand type) with the line marked by **** but am not sure why?

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: improper operand type

Comment: You can't use two memory operands with a mov instruction.

Comment: Is that because q is a memory address?

Comment: Yes, `q` is being treated as a memory operand.

Comment: so how would I move q to where si is pointing. Thats the part where I am getting confused. Do i simply remove the [si] = si?

Comment: You `mov` the value at `q` into a free register temporarily and then move the value of that temporary register to `[si]`

Comment: okay thanks. it works now.